# Python: Redirect logging to a file then direct it back

Tags: python, logging

My code calls funcA and funcB from two different imported module (whose code I cannot modify). I want whatever logs (error, info) encountered while calling those 2 functions (and whatever other functions those 2 functions may call) to be output to a file, and once those 2 funcs return, then revert to logging back to stdout as normal.

I know about setupLogging() of the logging module, but doing so will not impact funcA and funcB's logging because those belong to differnt modules and those modules import their logging as brand new instances.

What can I do ?

Comment: You can set up a function decorator for those functions to temporarily duplicate/redirect the output when they're called.  [This is a great article on understanding decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/)

Comment: But I cannot change those functions, those are from third party libraries, and those functions may call more functions.

Comment: You *can* change anything in python.  If you're just adjusting the stdout temporarily, there shouldn't be any impact.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 how do i do it ? I was hoping o use the logging module instead of low level stdout manipulation.

Comment: It's impossible to answer without seeing the specific library's code you're referring to, but the following should work: Figure out how those functions set up their logger, and import their logger into your code. Create your own [`FileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler) instance, and add *your* handler to *their* logger. Add a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.addFilter) to your handler to limit its logging to just those functions (e.g. by inspecting the LogRecord's `pathname` or `func`).